# How does Mandelbrot perturbation work?

Tags: c++, mandelbrot

Could someone please explain how perturbation described [in this paper](http://www.superfractalthing.co.nf/sft_maths.pdf) accelerates rendering the Mandelbrot set?

I know how to render the Mandelbrot set using the traditional method where many iterations are performed for each pixel, but I don't quite understand what is being described in that paper.

I compute the reference orbit like this:

```
std::complex<double> Xo(some_x, some_y);
std::complex<double> Xn(0,0);

for (int n = 0; n < maxIterations; ++n) {
  orbit.push_back(Xn);
  Xn = Xn * Xn + Xo;
}
```

Is that correct?  Then how do I use the reference orbit to compute all the other pixels?

Answer (score 0):

The border of the Mandelbrot size may have infinite length, but it's still an infinitely small part of the whole plane. For most pixels, the paper shows how you can calculate the local neighbourhood in limited precision.

You're working with a limited precision anyway (`double`) so it probably doesn't matter for you.

Comment: "Using equations (1) and (2) means that the time taken rendering Mandelbrot images is largely independent of depth and iteration count, and mainly depends on the complexity of the image being created"